# OpenCL Kernel with image transfer running slow

Tags: performance, opencl, nvidia, pyopencl, amd-gpu

I have a pretty simple OpenCL kernel, basically doing nothing more than defining its input:

```
__kernel void test(__read_only image3d_t d_multitest){}
```

My host side code is basic pyopencl to transfer an image to my device and run the kernel:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

platform = cl.get_platforms()[0]
devs = platform.get_devices()
device1 = devs[1]
h_test = np.zeros((64,512,512)).astype(np.float32,order='F')
mf = cl.mem_flags
ctx = cl.Context([device1])
Queue1 = cl.CommandQueue(ctx,properties=cl.command_queue_properties.PROFILING_ENABLE)
Queue2 = cl.CommandQueue(ctx,properties=cl.command_queue_properties.PROFILING_ENABLE)
event_list=[]

fi = open('Minimal.cl', 'r')
fstr = "".join(fi.readlines())
prg = cl.Program(ctx, fstr).build()
knl = prg.test

d_test = cl.Image(ctx,mf.READ_ONLY, cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.INTENSITY, cl.channel_type.FLOAT), h_test.shape)
e1 = cl.enqueue_copy(Queue1, d_test, h_test, is_blocking = False, origin = (0,0,0), region = h_test.shape)
knl.set_args(d_test)
cl.enqueue_nd_range_kernel(Queue2,knl,(512,512,64),None,wait_for=[e1,])
```

I am profiling this code on different devices and see, that the transfer time basically scales with the memory bandwith of the device, which is expected. On the other hand, my **Kernel execution time** varies wildly.

On Nvidia the Kernel execution duration is <<1ms.
[image: Profiling on Nvidia]

however, the exact same Kernel takes >20ms on AMDs implementation.
[image]

My question is, if this kind of overhead is tolerable, or if I am doing something basically wrong.

Hardware:

NVIDIA GeForce GTX TITAN X

AMD ATI Radeon 9 290X

Host:
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: you should add at least a simple addition and get its result to host to check if nvidia's compiler is optimizing it out

Comment: How are you profiling this code, using host-side timers, or by using OpenCL Events?

Comment: I am profiling the events returned from pyopencl's functions (in my example e1 etc.)